# How to mock a service that contains a static variable?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a question ? How can I mock a service that contains static variable?

This is my service

```
@Injectable()


export class AppConfigService {

    static settings: IAppConfig;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    load() {
        const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: IAppConfig) => {
                AppConfigService.settings = response as IAppConfig;
                resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
                reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

an this is my unit-test code:

```
describe('AppConfigService', () => {
    let service: AppConfigService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService}
            ]});
        service = TestBed.get(AppConfigService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('should ran load well', () => {
        expect(service.settings)......;
    });
```

I can not use service.settings, because settings is a static member of AppConfigService......

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused by your example. How are you testing your service when you override the injector with a mock.
But only considering your question, there is no way known to me. The access to a static member can't be overridden, just its content. In your example of an AppConfigService, you could qualify this service as a singleton by providing in root:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Now it's easy to mock this service whenever you test something with a dependency to your app config.